# How to handle No Content response using RxJava2 et Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm using `RxJava 2` & `Retrofit 2` (https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter) and I was wondering how to handle no response (204) type. 
In rxjava1 i was using `Observable<Void>` but it's not allowed by rxjava2 anymore (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0 -> Nulls)

Right now, i've hacked around to bypass Json parsing on a custom type (I called it NoContent) but I was wondering if there is a better way.

EDIT:

```
public class NoContent {
    public static class GsonTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<NoContent> {

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, NoContent value) throws IOException {
           out.nullValue();
        }

        @Override
        public NoContent read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
           return new NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have similar issue , any solution yet ?

Comment: Not that i'm aware of;

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Completable`, `Observable<ResponseBody>` or `Observable<Response<T>>` in the case you are going to get `204` responses without getting converter exceptions.

**Probably the best option here is to use `Completable`** as return type. All `2xx` responses from server will end up in `onComplete`. Other will end up in `onError`.

In case of `ResponseBody` all kind of valid HTTP responses won't be converted to Object and will end up in `onNext`, including `4xx` and `5xx` responses.

In case of `Response<T>` only 2xx responses will be converted, including, probably HTTP `204` response code. So I am not sure you should use it, although all valid HTTP responses in this case will also end up in `onNext`, including `4xx` and `5xx` responses.